# Order of product multiplication of $n$-cycles that may not commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\beta$ is a $10$-cycle. For which integers $i$ between $2$ and
$10$ is $\beta^i$ also a $10$-cycle?

The question I have is concerning the order of checking the powers of $\beta^i$.  Since there's no guarantee that $\beta^i$ and $\beta^j$ commute, how would I go about checking different powers of $\beta^i$?  Would it be $\beta^i \beta$ or $\beta \beta^i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The powers of $\beta$ form the cyclic group generated by $\beta$, so they commute with each other. But that's irrelevant for the problem at hand. Suppose $d=\gcd(i,10)>1$; then $\beta^i=\beta^{kd}$ where $i=kd$, so
$$
(\beta^i)^l=\beta^{kld}=\beta^{10k}=\iota
$$
where $10=ld$ and $\iota$ is the identity map. Thus the order of $\beta^i$ is less than $10$.

Suppose now $\gcd(i,10)=1$. Then prove that $\beta$ is a power of $\beta^{i}$ (hint: Bézout's theorem) and therefore $\beta^{i}$ must have order $10$.

Then count how many $i$ such that $2\le i\le10$ satisfy $\gcd(i,10)=1$.

Comment: What about the fact that if a pair of cycles have no entries in common then they commute.  Doesn't this cause a contradiction because the two cycles in question have the same elements in common?

Comment: @OliverG Disjoint cycles commute; non disjoint cycles *may* commute.

Comment: @OliverG Just think to $(123)(132)=(132)(123)$ or, more simply, to $(12)(12)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\beta^i$ and $\beta^j$ will commute because of associativity.